# How to send text into a input field within a frame using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, css-selectors, webdriver

I am a beginner at Selenium (using Python), and I was trying to do a simple application that would log in into my newspaper website, but I ran into problems to enter the login field which is in a different frame. I have looked around and found several answers that show how to select a different frame. However, I have done that, but when I try to send the text to the login field, nothing happens.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'http://www.valor.com.br'
path_to_chromedriver = 'chromedriver' 
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)
browser.get(url)
browser.find_element_by_id("login-valor").click()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser,10)
WebEl = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'cadunLoginModal')))

browser.switch_to_frame(browser.find_element_by_id("cadunLoginModal").find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
browser.find_element_by_id("login").send_keys("teste")
```

I try to send 'teste' to the login field, but nothing appears.

If I replace the last line by a click attempt...

```
browser.find_element_by_id("login").click()
```

... I end up getting the following message:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <iframe src="https://login.globo.com/login/6668?url=&amp;tam=WIDGET" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" cd_frame_id_="4bed04b195abe0173e2400a792245d31"></iframe> is not clickable at point (599, 298). Other element would receive the click: <iframe src="https://login.globo.com/login/6668?url=&amp;tam=WIDGET" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"></iframe>
  (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578706 (5f725d1b4f0a4acbf5259df887244095596231db),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64)
```

It looks like as if the field was not visible, but it is.

Could you please help to throw some light at this issue? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As per the *url* `http://www.valor.com.br` to send a *character sequence* to the login field you need to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element with text as **Login** to be clickable*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the *input element* **E-mail** to be clickable.
- You can use the following solution.
- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  url = 'http://www.valor.com.br'
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  browser.get(url)
  WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.topo_login>a.login-valor.login-globo"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src='https://login.globo.com/login/6668?url=&tam=WIDGET']")))
  WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.ng-pristine.ng-invalid.ng-invalid-required[name='login']"))).send_keys("teste")
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: teste]